# How to remove empty spaces generated by grid view

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout

I want to apply categorise selection for my flutter app. I'm a beginner in flutter. I've tried to my very best to get here but I don't know how to remove these empty spaces.

In the body of the homescreen.dart I've written the following code.

```
Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: KDefaultPadding),
        child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: products.length,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 0.75,
            mainAxisSpacing: KDefaultPadding,
            crossAxisSpacing: KDefaultPadding,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ItemCard(
            product:
                products[index].tag == "chicken" ? products[index] : null,
            press: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => DetailScreen(
                  product: products[index],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

and in the item card.dart I've written the following.

```
    class ItemCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Product product;
  final Function press;

  const ItemCard({
    Key key,
    this.product,
    this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (product != null) {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: press,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(KDefaultPadding),
              // height: 180,
              // width: 160,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: product.color,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
              ),
              child: Hero(
                  tag: "${product.id}",
                  child: Image.asset(
                    product.image,
                  )),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: KDefaultPadding / 4),
              child: Text(
                product.title,
                style:
                    TextStyle(color: kTextColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "$kCurrency${product.price}",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: kTextLightColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }
```

}

and the output I got is this.

[image]

initial is this...
[image]

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: This probably might be a container and not empty spaces since you are returning container when the product is null, try to give red color to container in the else statement within card.dart and tell me please.

Comment: No I want to remove that empty container and only have three widgets

Comment: Yes i got your point, The issue is that you are passing product:
                products[index].tag == "chicken" ? products[index] : null, to the card.dart, so when the product is null you are rendering an empty container, it is a container and not an empty space, you have to filter your array befire passing it the the GridBuilder

Comment: can I know how to do that. I don't wanna sound rude or bossy but I know the concept but having hard time implementing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this `products.length` to `products.where((product) => product.tag == 'chicken').length` to do not put unexpected product into GridView.